# kendoUI grid-command-click-event-triggered-multiple-times

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI grid presented in a mobal window (kendoWindow). The grid has a column command with a click event:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    columns:[
        ...
    { command: { text: "Delete", click: ContactDelete }],
    }];
```

This  delete Command Button is calling the method multiple time as much as rows are there in the grid,means if we have 1  rows  in the grid then once ,2 rows it will call twice and so on also I'm having problem of rebinding the grid after deleting the rows,Even i tried with grid.destroy and lot other options.

[Sample Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishshri/trzrj/43/)

Answer (score 0):

create custom events like below and onclick event call a function ...

```
command.Custom("Edit").Text(" ").Click("EditRole");
```

Comment: I have Created Custom Events only,its there in my sample code,I'm not exactly clear how you are asking it.